# How to check obfuscation results of flutter app?

Tags: android, flutter, obfuscation, minify

In native android development I could check whether my minifyEnabled had taken effect.

I used this script (in linux) which allows me to extract the apk and view the java files to see if my code is readable, or has been obfuscated :

```
#! /bin/bash
d2j=/work/installs/dex2jar-2.0
jdgui=/work/installs/jd-gui-1.4.0.jar
apk_loc=/work/projects/my_app/build/app/outputs/app-release.apk

mkdir -p /work/tmp/dex
rm -rf /work/tmp/dex/*
cd /work/tmp
cp $apk_loc ./app-release.zip
unzip app-release.zip -d dex
cd dex

chmod +x $d2j/*.sh
$d2j/d2j-dex2jar.sh classes.dex

java -jar $jdgui classes-dex2jar.jar
```

If I use this script on a flutter apk, I don't see any files containing anything related to my original code.

Comment: So there is nothing readable?

Comment: If OP is assuming Flutter compiles to Java classes - it doesn't. See: [Flutter - How does it work behind the scenes?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43854798/295004)

Answer (score 1):

Flutter's dart code is compiled to native and embedded to flutter.so runtime, so decompiling flutter is not as easy as byte code of java/kotlin
However decompiling .so file is possible. You can use the toolchains inside the android ndk to perform the type of disassembling you want to

```
./android-ndk-r15b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-objdump -T "flutter.so | less
```

but this is just give you an objdump.

Comment: thanks - but where does this come from? I don't see an arm-linux-androideabi-objdump installed on my system.

Comment: have you downloaded the Android NDK? 
https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/

Comment: I read this document relating to this : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Obfuscating-Dart-Code - it states that "Code obfuscation hides function and class names in your compiled Dart code, making it difficult for an attacker to reverse engineer your proprietary app."

Comment: I tried the ndk download and viewed the output on libflutter.so, but it does not seem to relate to my original code in any way that I can discern ?