# What is the difference between Obfuscating Dart code and obfuscation via build.gradle file in a Flutter application?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, obfuscation

I found 2 ways to obfuscate a Flutter application:

1. https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#enable
2. https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/obfuscate

What is the difference between these 2 ways? And does a Flutter app need Obfuscation?

Comment: The first option describes how to obfuscate java (Android) and does not seem to be Flutter related. Afaics, the second option is indeed what is needed to obfuscate Flutter.  For the second part I suggest to have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52767806/should-we-obfuscate-the-dart-code-in-flutter-apps