# Why was Flutter implemented in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

Why Flutter team decided to use Dart as main language?

Dart is compiled to JavaScript so why not using JavaScript as the programming language of Flutter? I mean the idea of: "it compiles to native" does not stand as there are other JavaScript framework to use or compile (?) to native code (like https://nativescript.org/)

[Edit]
A related question might be : [Flutter - How does it work behind the scenes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43854647/flutter-how-does-it-work-behind-the-scenes)

Comment: Look up react native if you want something very similar to flutter but using Javascript instead of Dart

Comment: See https://flutter.dev/docs/resources/faq#why-did-flutter-choose-to-use-dart and https://hackernoon.com/why-flutter-uses-dart-dd635a054ebf.  Also, Dart is transpiled to JavaScript only for web platforms.

Answer (score 6):

Your premise is wrong. Dart is not compiled to JS.

It is *only* compiled to JS when you target the web, one of many possible targets and not the first one. As always with JS, it's not done because JS is a good language to work with, it's because it's the only thing that will reliably (*cough*) work in browsers.

You can read a more in depth explanation in the [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/resources/faq#why-did-flutter-choose-to-use-dart)

Answer (score 2):

dart language has lot of feature that doesn't exist in javascript
and google create dart to replace js in web so they decide to push further dart language more and they succed with it.dart language more power than js

Comment: Well...1. When they started Dart JavaScript was indeed less powerful but latest version of JavaScript filled the gap 2. When debugging an application you need less layers...so having Dart converted to JavaScript makes this task cumbersome.